# php sql query from one db insert in another

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a script which connects to one database run a SQL query and then is trying to import that into another server DB, I have configured all correct I believe but I cannot make it work.

```
echo date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A"). " Collecting Sage CRM records.\r\n";
$sql="SELECT StockItem.Code AS 'Stock Code',
StockItem.Name AS 'Description', 
WarehouseItem.ConfirmedQtyInStock+WarehouseItem.UnconfirmedQtyInStock AS 'Available Stock', 
StockItem.FreeStockQuantity AS 'Free Stock', 
WarehouseItem.QuantityAllocatedStock AS 'Allocated Stock', 
WarehouseItem.QuantityOnPOPOrder AS 'Qty on PO', 
Warehouse.Name AS 'Warehouse Location', 
StockItem.AnalysisCode1 AS 'Product Class', 
ProductGroup.Code AS 'Product Category'
FROM MMS_Global.dbo.ProductGroup ProductGroup, 
MMS_Global.dbo.StockItem StockItem, MMS_Global.dbo.Warehouse Warehouse, 
MMS_Global.dbo.WarehouseItem WarehouseItem
WHERE WarehouseItem.WarehouseID = Warehouse.WarehouseID 
AND StockItem.ItemID = WarehouseItem.ItemID 
AND ProductGroup.ProductGroupID = StockItem.ProductGroupID 
AND ((StockItem.StockItemStatusID Like '0%'));";

$rs=sqlsrv_query($consage, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' )) or die ( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

$record=0;
$fullcount=sqlsrv_num_rows ($rs ) ;
echo date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A"). " Adding ".$fullcount." Stock records to in ACT!.\r\n";



While($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($rs))
    {
    $row[0] = str_replace("'", "''", $row[0]);
    $sql3="insert into CUST_Inventory (
        InventoryID,
        [CUST_StockCode_065752395],
        [CUST_Description_065825443],
        [CUST_AvailableStock_065849679],
        [CUST_FreeStock_065906993],
        [CUST_AllocatedStock_065925572],
        [CUST_QtyonPO_065941916],
        [CUST_WarehouseLocation_070001667],
        [CUST_ProductClass_070019497],
        [CUST_ProductCategory_070847021],
        EDITDATE,
        CREATEDATE,
        CREATEUSERID,
        MANAGEUSERID,
        ISPRIVATE,
        EDITUSERID)
        Values(
        Newid(),
        '".$row['Stock Code']."',
        '".$row['Description']."',
        '".$row['Available Stock']."',
        '".$row['Free Stock']."',
        '".$row['Allocated Stock']."',
        '".$row['Qty on PO']."',
        '".$row['Warehouse Location']."',
        '".$row['Product Class']."',
        '".$row['Product Category']."',
        getdate(),
        getdate(),
        CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'F43F5A16-1E5F-4C81-B7C9-FA6350954D24'),
        CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'F43F5A16-1E5F-4C81-B7C9-FA6350954D24'),
        0,
        CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'F43F5A16-1E5F-4C81-B7C9-FA6350954D24')
    );";


    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $con, $sql3 );
if( $stmt === false ) {
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
        }
    }
}
}
echo date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A")." ".$record." of ".$fullcount." records added.\r\n";
?>
```

My error is always at the first line and it doesn't insert any data, and I cannot figure out why, anyone can help, please?

Thanks.

The script is trying to import but is giving me an error at the first line, I had a look and I cannot see anything wrong

The error I get is `]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '.00000' to data type int.`

I cannot figure out what is wrong as the php code looks fine the sql query works fine.

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: And you have 16 fields in the INSERT INTO, but only 15 values in the VALUES part. Also, always use parameters in your statements.

Comment: @Zhorov, the error is         echo " error on Stock code ".$row[0]."\r\n";

Comment: I think you should access the value by its right index like this $row['Stock Code']

Comment: Hi @Zhorov, I did that and the error I have is:SQLSTATE: 42000<br />code: 102<br />message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'.<br /> I cannot see anything wrong with the sql query as it is working fine.

Comment: @Parfait, I'm not sure how to do that as I have two diffrent servers.

Comment: I have adjusted the code as per below

Comment: Look into [Linked Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) if you have permission to do so. Then you can append in one call and avoid looping and concatenating: `INSERT INTO CUST_Inventory ... SELECT .... FROM [linkedserver].MMS_Global.dbo.ProductGroup ...`

Answer (score 1):

Sorted, I had to adjust all the query to do

````
CAST(WarehouseItem.QuantityAllocatedStock AS varchar(50)) ,
CAST(WarehouseItem.QuantityOnPOPOrder AS varchar(50)), ```
````